# SSIS 2008, Excel 2007 formatting excel columns properly (Exporting, not importing)

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm running into some formatting issues with exporting data to an excel 2007 spreadsheet.

I have a template file that has the columns formatted correctly, but when the data is exported it doesn't get the correct formats (currency, short date, etc.)

I'm thinking I have 2 options

Have excel autorun a macro.  (hate that idea)

Format the data before it gets to excel and make it string data only. (I don't like that idea either as you are going to get those irritating data conversion arrows next to each cell)

I've used the IMEX=1 trick to get around the data import issues before, but is there a special trick for exporting?

thanks,

Comment: Could you provide an example of how a date or currency is wrong? What is the DB format and how is it formatted in Excel?

Comment: Help me plis, i need do the same!! you could do this work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much formatting and gnashing of teeth, I came down to the final solution.  It appears that you still need the hidden row at the top for excel to use.  That determines whether the data is formatted as numeric or string.  If you want to do any more formatting, then you need to add in a script task to your SSIS package.  I just threw the following lines into a .net script task at the end of my processing and it fixed it right up.

Please don't puke on the DailyWTF quality code ;-)

```
        Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\reports\Report.xlsx")
    'This is the long ass Accounting Format'
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()
```

Comment: This cannot be done as Excel interop need to be install in the server to perform this. Which is not recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

I spent ages trying to figurure this out.

What you need to do is have a hidden row of data in the spreadsheet you are exporting to.

SSIS will place the values into the spreadsheet, and assume the type is that of the row immediately above. So the data row needs to be the last row in the spreadsheet, and the data in each column needs to be of the type you want it to be.

You would think there was a better way of doing this. There isn't. Sorry :-)

Comment: Close...Oh so close...  Tried that one.  Unfortunately, it doesn't pick the exact right format.  for example, in one column, I'll have the data formatted as accounting ($    0.00) When it outputs it actually picks the generic number format with 2 decimal places, no dollar sign.  I'm not exactly sure how much I care about the details, but I'd like to know if I'm really just stuck.

Comment: @James-Wiseman I'm trying to get round a similar issue to this, just trying to work out where to insert the hidden row of data, could you assist at all?

Comment: I'd make it the first row of the SS, and then hide that row.

Comment: @James-Wiseman - will that be effected if the excel export doesn't start populating data until cell B5?? I use a select query as per below in the excel connection string?
SELECT     *
FROM         [Sheet1$b5:F5]

Comment: Suggest then you do some sort of union in your query with a select of dummy data to form the first row.

Comment: Great!! That did the trick. Adding the row with formats and hidding it worked for me!

Comment: I actually used this solution, because it was easy; however, it is not perfect.  The hidden row can be confusing, mess up calculations, and doesn't allow full formatting flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is so simple it will make you scream.  Just use the CREATE TABLE SQL command from a SQL task box in SSIS.  Set the connection type to EXCEL.  Here are the steps :

Let's use 'TEST' as the tab name on the spreadhseet.

1.) Copy the template file to a new file.

2.) Create a SQL task, set connection type to Excel and use the connection string to your newly created Excel file.  Use the below code as a sample :

DROP TABLE `TEST`

GO

3.) Create another SQL task (using the same settings) and use the following code :

CREATE TABLE `TEST`

(   `Column1` Integer,
    `Column2` DATETIME,
    `Column3` NVARCHAR(50),
    `Column4` MONEY
)

GO

You can now start writing data.  A couple of things I ran into is the I had to use the ` character instead of the ' for a comma.  Also, I tried using both the DROP & CREATE commands in one SQL task but it didn't work for me, so I used two.