# SQL SSIS Export to Excel, Casting the Decimal Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

```
Select CAST (ROUND (t_paid,2) as numeric(36,2)) as [Copay] from Sales

Select CAST (ROUND (t_paid,2) as decimal(18,2)) as [Copay] from Sales
```

From the SQL, I can see the output values as **0.00**

I am exporting this to a Spreadsheet (.xls ) format. In the Excel Sheet, i am getting the value as 0.

As per the requirement, i need to get all whole numbers as 0.00 or 1.00.

How to cast the values while exporting to excel in the SSIS Package ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original Answer: Convert numeric to text.

Based on the feedback below the answer has changed.

For this scenario, a numeric output is required for downstream functionality. The cause of the issue is the general formatting which is performed by excel. In this case, it is necessary to edit the generated spreadsheet through code. Links from the comments are included below which discuss how to accomplish this task.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/390b0812-e40e-4bab-9315-31710f6128c4/ssis-script-task-excel-workbooksopen?forum=sqlintegrationservices

[SSIS 2008, Excel 2007 formatting excel columns properly (Exporting, not importing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954582/ssis-2008-excel-2007-formatting-excel-columns-properly-exporting-not-importin)

Comment: No, thats not the solution. It has to be Number Format.

Comment: Values such as 76.12  or 2.34 are getting correctly in the Excel Sheet. When it comes to the whole number such as 2.00 it goes like "2". whoever get this report,they do some calculation. So it has to be Number format

Comment: Look into formatting the excel column to number with two places then. Excel auto formats the values which is why whole numbers are not displaying all places. I imagine 2.1 is shown as 2.1 and not 2.10 as well.

Comment: Okay, i should do that then. I wonder anyway to write a piece of code inside the SSIS Package which can do this automatically

Comment: Looks like you have to programmatically edit the workbook after you generate it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/390b0812-e40e-4bab-9315-31710f6128c4/ssis-script-task-excel-workbooksopen?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Formatting an Excel Column is already discussed over here. I am trying the syntax as discussed over here                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954582/ssis-2008-excel-2007-formatting-excel-columns-properly-exporting-not-importin